# Should we plot the roc curve for each class?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm doing a binary classification .. I've an imbalanced data and I've used the svm weight in trying to mitigate the situation ...
As you can see I've calculated and plot the roc curve for each class and I've got the following plot:
[image]
It looks like the two classes some up to one .. and I'm n't sure if I'm doing the right thing or not because its the first time for me to draw my own roc curve ... I'm using Scikit learn to plot ... is it right to plot each class alone .. and is the classifier failing in classifying the blue class ?

this is the code that I've used to get the plot:

```
y_pred = clf.predict_proba(X_test)[:,0] # for calculating the probability of the first class
y_pred2 = clf.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1] # for calculating the probability of the second class
fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(y_test, y_pred)
auc=metrics.auc(fpr, tpr)
print "auc for the first class",auc

fpr2, tpr2, thresholds2 = metrics.roc_curve(y_test, y_pred2)
auc2=metrics.auc(fpr2, tpr2)
print "auc for the second class",auc2

# ploting the roc curve
plt.plot(fpr,tpr)
plt.plot(fpr2,tpr2)

plt.xlim([0.0,1.0])
plt.ylim([0.0,1.0])
plt.title('Roc curve')
plt.xlabel('False positive rate')
plt.ylabel('True positive rate')
plt.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.show()
```

I know there is a better way to write as a dictionary for example but I was just trying to see the curve first

Comment: Can you show the code that you've used to get the data and plot please?

Comment: of course I'll update my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic) entry for a all your ROC curve needs :)

`predict_proba` returns class probabilities for each class. The first column contains the probability of the first class and the second column contains the probability of the second class. Note that the two curves are rotated versions of each other. That is because the class probabilities add up to 1.

The documentation of [`roc_curve`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html) states that the second parameter must contain

> Target scores, can either be probability estimates **of the positive class** or confidence values.

This means you have to pass the probabilities that corresponds to class 1. Most likely this is the second column.

You get the blue curve because you passed the probabilities of the wrong class (first column). Only the green curve is correct.

It does not make sense to compute ROC curves for each class, because the ROC curve describes *the ability of the classifier to distinguish two classes*. You have only one curve per classifier.

<s>The specific problem is a coding mistake.</s>

`predict_proba` returns class probabilities (1 if it's certainly the class, 0 if it is definitly not the class, usually it's something in-between).

`metrics.roc_curve(y_test, y_pred)` now compares class labels against probabilities, which is like comparing pears against apple juice.

You should use `predict` instead of `predict_proba` to predict class labels and not probabilities. These can be compared against the true class labels for computing the ROC curve. Incidentally, this also removes the option to plot a second curve - you only get one curve for the classifier, not one for each class.

Comment: But here they use the predict_proba as well to plot the roc curve:http://cbio.ensmp.fr/~nvaroquaux/scikit-learn/auto_examples/plot_roc.html .... and what does probas_[:, 1] mean ? does it mean for class 1 ? It gives the same curve that I end up with !

Comment: Look like I was wrong. The function really takes the estimated probabilities. However, you still made a mistake. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I am sorry I know that I have lots of questions :( .. can you this as well : http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html they have computed the roc curve for a specific class as well and because of that I got confused ! why would they compute it for each class if it should be just for the classifier ?

Comment: This example extends ROC curves to more than two classes. They essentially do one curve for each 1-vs-all classification.

Comment: I see thank you .. Everything is clear now .. And yes the green plot was by sending the probability of class 1(not 0)... And this what I should keep as you said ..many thanks

Comment: "You have only one curve per classifier". Correct. In particular, starting from the ROC curve corresponding to a given interpretation of the classes, the ROC curve with opposite classes (T<->F) can be obtained by reflecting the chart along the falling diagonal (⟍). This is because TPr+FPr'=TNr'+FPr'=1 and FPr+TPr'=FPr+TNr=1.

Answer (score 0):

you have to rethink the whole approach. ROC curve indicates the quality of different classifiers at different "probability" thresholds and not the classes. Usually, a straight line with a slope of 0.5 is the benchmark for the classifiers whether your classifier is able to beat a random guess.

Answer (score 0):

It's because while building ROC for class 0, it considers '0' in y_test as Boolean False for your target class.

Try changing:
`fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(y_test, y_pred)` to `fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(1-y_test, y_pred)`